# Commit message hook on github

Tags: github, jira, githooks

I am trying to setup a pre-receive hook in github that I used to use on STASH. In STASH, I had a pre-receive hook that used to enforce "A custom commit message that should have a JIRA number included in it".

Now, I am trying to understand what would be the best way to do something similar on github. If I split it up, it would be:

- Requiring a custom commit message.
- Every commit should include an existing JIRA.
- Enforce this on any pull request as well.

Eg: TEST-1 Adding the first commit message.

Can anybody here help me, how can this be done ?

Answer (score 2):

GitHub only [offers webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/), which allows you to listen to and react to [certain events](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#events), including the push.

But that only allows you to react to a push (like a post-receive hook would), not to prevent it.

You could build a listener to that push event which would:

- examine the latest commit just pushed
- reset to `HEAD~1` if the commit doesn't follow the expected policy (`push --force`)

But that would be tricky for the user who initially pushed that commit to realize that said commit just disappeared from the GitHub repo.

---

A better solution would be to setup a bare repo in a server where you could setup that pre-receive hook: if that commit passes, then a post-receive hook would push it to the intended GitHub repo.

But depending on your team, it might be difficult to setup a repo which is accessible by everyone.

Comment: In your second solution, I would be asking the developers to push to a different repo though right ? If thats the case then I am guessing the developers, wouldn't like to clone from one repo and push to a different repo, and they would want me gone ASAP :).

Comment: @Jason no, I can assure you they will not want you gone ASAP, this is a common setup which is enabled by the distributed nature of Git. Having multiple remote is a feature to be taken advantage of.

Comment: Here is a take, setting up bare repo is ok, but what if someone creates a pull request from some branch or a forked repo and then merges code directly to the main repo ?

Comment: @Jason the idea behind a fork repo is to allow "someone" to push to it because he/she doesn't have any right to push anything to the main repo. So the main repo is safe.

Comment: Can I create a hook in github that will listen to a Pull Request creation and reject it, if the message in the pull request is not correct ?

Comment: @Jason you sure can, considerning a PR generates its own event. I mentioned it before in http://stackoverflow.com/a/31604179/6309.

Comment: Can the web hooks be configured/setup without using ngrok ?
@Vonc, do you have sample web-hooks that you have created or the steps to setup it up ? Thanks

Comment: @Jason Not for PR. A few interesting links: https://gist.github.com/bjhess/2726012, http://chloky.com/github-pull-req-webhook/, https://gist.github.com/jimCresswell/7038683