# Is it possible to restrict PR/MR creation to the branch author only?

Tags: github, gitlab, bitbucket

Is it possible to configure such a restriction that a PR/MR from a branch can be created only by the branch's author?

I am interested in all possible solutions for github, bitbucket and gitlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no restriction on the PR/MR creation side (for instance, on GitHub: "[How to disable pull requests in GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40008924/6309)")

There is the notion of protected branches ([for GitHub](https://github.community/t5/Support-Protips/Best-practices-for-protected-branches/ba-p/10224) or [GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html))

GitHub has then the notion of [status check](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-required-status-checks) (no [yet for GitLab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/15930), also webhook can help): you could code as a "status rejected" the fact the PR/MR was created by a different author then the previous commit's author.

Keep in mind though there is no "author branch" per se with Git: only commits author, each commit being part of one or several branches.