# How to create a tag on GitHub when a PR is merged?

Tags: git, github, githooks, pull-request

My current workflow requires a version Bump on every PR, so I would like to take advantage of that and automatically create a tag on GitHub on every PR merge, so it appears in the "release" section.

I've seen that I can write a post-merge hook. My doubt is if that hook runs locally in my machine, remotely on GitHub, or both (given that I merge the PR on GitHub, and not locally. What's the case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I can write a post-merge hook. My doubt is if that hook runs locally in my machine, remotely on GitHub, or both

2015: It will certainly not run on GitHub (that wouldn't be safe for GitHub to run any user-provided hook).

What you can have is a [Webhook on pull request](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/): by listening to its JSON payload, you can add a tag and push it back to GitHub if the **[PR event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestevent)** indicated a *merged* PR.
(That is, if the `action` is "`closed`", and the `merged` key is "`true`")

---

2020: it will certainly run on GitHub: that is called [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions).

In the OP's case, the [GitHub Tag Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-tag).

> A GitHub Action to automatically bump and tag master, on merge, with the latest SemVer formatted version. Works on any platform.
>
> ### Usage

```yaml
name: Bump version
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
        with:
          # Fetches entire history, so we can analyze commits since last tag
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Bump version and push tag
        uses: mathieudutour/github-tag-action@v4.5
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

A similar and more up-to-date Action: [github-tag-action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-tag-bump).
See "[Creating A Github Action to Tag Commits](https://itnext.io/creating-a-github-action-to-tag-commits-2722f1560dec?gi=5a371be4ca5c)" from **[Nick Sjostrom](https://github.com/anothrNick)**.

```yaml
name: Bump version
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: Bump version and push tag
      uses: anothrNick/github-tag-action@master
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        REPO_OWNER: anothrNick
```